# Why isn't DataContext not updating with external database changes?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql

If I change data within Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio while my application is running, LINQ will not get the new data, even if I run

```
myContext.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues)
```

The only way to get the new changes (that I've found so far...) is to recreate the data context.

```
myContext.Dispose();
myContext = new MyDataContext();
```

I must be blind and this has to be really obvious, but I've wasted enough time on this to allow myself to post this dumb question... -_-''

Thanks!

**Edit**

When I load data from SQL:

```
myBindingSource.DataSource = myContext.myTable.Where(o => o.id != 0).OrderBy(o => o.name);
```

Comment: How are you getting data from the database, via a Linq query or something else? Can you post an example of a query? Also, what does SQL Server Profiler show when you do a refresh without recreating the context?

Comment: Edited to add the loading. How do you use SQL Server Profiler?

Comment: Once you pull data from the context, its set. All you need is to rerun your query when the data changes to bind "myBindingSource.DataSource"

Comment: And how do I do that? Perhaps you could write an answer :)

Comment: Three questions: 1. Could you be missing some objects in your call to Refresh? 2. Are you changing any objects, or using the context read-only. 3. Why do you have a long context lifetime anyway? Why not just recreate the datacontext if that's working for you?

Comment: 1. Missing some objects? 2. Changing 3. Cause I though it wasn't recommended to recreate the DataContext when it's not needed? Just felt like a hack fix to me... Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My concept was flawed and a DbContext should not be kept longer then the queries you need to execute. That said, if I want to refresh my data, I should just get a new DbContext instance and refill my data source.

Answer (score -1):

let the connectionstrin be :

```
string pp = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
```

and update task be the below mentioned :

```
  public async Task callupdate()
        {
            try
            {
                int ppp = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1ID.Text);
                DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext(pp);

                Person person = dc.Persons.Single(c => c.BusinessEntityID == ppp);
                person.PersonType = Convert.ToString(PersonTypecomboBox1.SelectedItem);
                person.PersonType = Convert.ToString(PersonTypecomboBox1.SelectedItem);
                if (NameStylecomboBox1.SelectedText == "False")
                    person.NameStyle = false;
                else
                    person.NameStyle = true;
                person.Title = Convert.ToString(TitlecomboBox1.SelectedItem);
                person.FirstName = FirstNametextBox2.Text;
                person.MiddleName = MiddleNametextBox3.Text;
                person.LastName = LastNametextBox4.Text;
                person.Suffix = SuffixtextBox5.Text;
                person.EmailPromotion = Convert.ToInt32(EmailPromotiontextBox6.Text);
                person.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Today;
                dc.SubmitChanges();
            }
            catch(Exception exp)
                {

                }

        }
```

instead of  `DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();`

`DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext(pp);`

Vby calling `SubmitChanges()` the update data that is the object of our class is actually being written in the actual database

Comment: How is this at all an answer to this question?